# Which one is better, opening two terminal or running a command using & in this case

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to do a loopback test on can bus using this site,

[this1](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_configure_and_use_CAN_bus)

and

[this2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7027&start=284)

In the second one, a second terminal is to be opened (which I can't do as minicom will only open one, and opening next one will be locked)

I need to use two commands to check the loopback,

```
cansend
candump
```

I am not good at shell commands and redirection, (but I did remember using & and the background process will wait until it get input) so what i did was this

```
#candump can0 &
#cansend can0 <can_id>#{data}
     can0 <can_id> data
```

So I get the data, but I did not see anywhere that anyone suggested to use candump in background.

Is my way correct/valid?

Comment: If you're doing `cansend can0 ID#DATA` , then backgrounding should be fine, but if you're going to send multiple things, i.e. run `cansend can0` then backgrounding might not be best - if I recall correctly background commands get /dev/null assigned as stdin.  But if you can use two terminal tabs - there's no reason make it complex.

Comment: As of now I am doing only one cansend. I don't know how can I open another shell session, as the commands are runnning inside android shell,which I am seeing over uart(minicom) on host PC. Opening another android terminal tab on same PC
?? How?

Comment: Um, if you're using Android shell, that's probably a more relevant question for android.stackexchange.com But you could get away with either `screen` or `tmux` for that purpose.